# remove index.php and 301 redirect with codeigniter and htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have 5 domains all pointing to the same server, and for SEO purposes I have setup an canonical meta link specifying the main domain.

My question is, how do I remove the index.php from the url and also 301 redirect all my domains to the main domain?

Here is my .htaccess to remove the index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Here is my .htaccess to 301 redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I tried to merge the two but then I got some weird results, it would redirect the domain, but place the entire url as a paramter of the page...

Comment: so what are the weird results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the redirect to happen before the routing rule (the one that sends everything to `/index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```